# Jenkins pipeline when condition print expression rather than compare

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have to write a pipeline that Builds Terraform infrastructure on Monday and destroy on Friday. I'm trying to determine whether to build or destroy depending on the result of `$(date '+%a')`, so here's what the condition looks like at the moment:

```
when {
      beforeAgent true
      expression { 
                 // Using 'Wed' because today is Wednesday
                  return  sh(returnStdout: true, script: '$(date +%a)') == 'Wed'
      }
}
```

The only problem is every time I ran it, Jenkins shell print the result of `sh(returnStdout: true, script: '$(date +%a)')` rather than as a comparison value.

```
[Pipeline] sh
14:52:03 [teardown] Running shell script
14:52:04 + date +%a
14:52:04 + Wed
14:52:04 /jenkins-slave/workspace/teardown@tmp/durable-524bef20/script.sh: 2: /jenkins-slave/workspace/teardown@tmp/durable-524bef20/script.sh: Wed: not found
```

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S I'm very new to Jenkins like 2 days of use, apologies in advance if I'm being blunt.

Comment: This is a shell syntax error with your command. `$(date +%a)` is going to execute the return of `date +%a`. You want `date +%a` as the shell command.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks for the response, I change the logic to `sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'date +%a')` now it think its a string rather than a command. I also tried `sh('date +%a')` that returns same logs as in the question. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Matt Schuchard in comment your initial problem is the `$(date +%a)` that make him execute the result of the command `date +%a`.

But it's entirely resolving your issue as `sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'date +%a')` will not return you `"Wed"` for Wednesday but `"Wed\n"`.

Try this :

```
steps {
    script {
        String v = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'date +%a')
        print v
        print v.trim()
    }
}
```

and the output will look like :

[image]

So you can either do like in my example and use `trim()` :

```
when {
    beforeAgent true
    expression { sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'date +%a').trim() == 'Wed' }
}
```

Or as Jenkins pipelines are Groovy script you could do it in a Groovy way like :

```
def week = [1:'Sunday', 2:'Monday', 3:'Tuesday', 4:'Wednesday', 5:'Thursday', 6:'Friday', 7:'Saturday']

pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('stage'){
            when {
                beforeAgent true
                expression { week[new Date()[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK]] == 'Wednesday' }
            }
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, This worked. Groovy script way didn't work, probably because I'm running on a sandbox, but good to know when I move out of the sandbox and to an actual script. Thanks again